"Permission denied" on an Insert even though user has all privileges on the Sequence
I am trying to Insert lines in a table with a non-admin User which should have all the necessary rights to perform the Insert. I do however get a "permission denied for sequence 'id_seq'" when doing so.
The error is ERROR: permission denied for sequence id_seq SQL state: 42501
Admin user is the owner of the Table and Sequence which is used to automatically increment the line Id : id int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass)
User has all rights to Use/Insert/Update/Delete on the table + Usage, Select, Update rights on the id_seq Sequence
User can insert a line in the Table by forcing the Id to be defined and not let the nextvalkick in.
I have created other Users with all the rights and the same error happens, only Admin as the owner of that sequence seems to be able to use it.
I am out of ideas about what could be missing and have not found any other advice than making sure my User has all the rights on the sequence itself

You are neither showing the statement nor the exact error message, so all I can do is guess that the user doesn't have the USAGE privilege on the sequence's schema.

This is exactly why I prefer to use an IDENTITY column instead of a default sequence. See https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-10-identity-columns/

I actually found the issue. I had an id_seq sequence in the same Schema than the one the Table belongs to. But the sequence used by the Table is another id_seq sequence which resides in  the public Schema. This one did not have the proper Usage grants for my User. I am not expert enough to figure out how I ended up in this situation of having to sequences. Is it common to have a sequence in the public schema for a table in another schema?

Yet another reason to user IDENTITY column as indicated by Frank Heikens above.
